# how to ggsave a plot with filename 'fig_x.tiff' where x is the quarto cross reference number?

Tags: r, quarto

Quartos cross reference functionality allows for automatic numbering of figures, tables, etc and makes it easy to cross-reference them in the markdown.

However, is there a way to access those references within the r code? I assume the cross-reference numbers are stored as variables in the render function somehow and would like to use them to save figures to file (ggsave) with the figur number as part of the file name.

In the (non-functional) example below, I am looking for a solution for ?? in the fn assignment.

````
---
title: "An example"
format: html
---

In markdown we cross-reference @fig-my_fig.

```{r figure_distribution_by_probe_and session}
#| label: fig-my_fig

my_figure <- data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y=y, x=x)) + geom_boxplot()

fn <- paste0("Figure_number_",??,".png")

ggsave(filename=fn,
       plot=my_figure, 
       device="png")
```
````

Comment: You can get Quarto to save your figures automatically, without the need for a call to `ggsave`.  See, for example, [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4254) or [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/2767), but there are some limitations, as explained in the links.